# Data reduction program

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

This is my first program in Python and first time I'm writing in dynamically typed language. I have substituted real `detectPeaks` function with a simple placeholer. I'm aware of several problems with this program.

I still don't quite know how to 'live with' Python scoping, hence the `qFix`function. I didn't bother to find a better name since I want to rewrite whole program.

Doing anything outside of any function seems unclean to me. It seems that it is ok in Python. Am I right? # It did allow me to have global `cmdArgs` object witch makes logic connected to cmd arguments clean.

I'm also concerned with naming functions and variables and structure of the program. The program does not have to be very flexible I would get away with hardcoding most of the things but prefer not unless it would complicate code significantly.

```
__version__ = dirt3

import sys, os.path, argparse, glob
import numpy as np

def detectPeaks(in_list):
    in_list = [s.replace(',', '.') for s in in_list]
    in_list.pop() # remove "\r\n"
    X = np.array(map(float, in_list[:2]))
    Y = np.array(map(float, in_list[2:]))

    XminIndex = np.argmin(X)
    YminIndex = np.argmin(Y)
    val = X[XminIndex] + Y[YminIndex]

    return (XminIndex, YminIndex, val)

def processFileLine(line):
    No, time, A, B = line.split('\t')[0], line.split('\t')[1], line.split("\t")[2::2], line.split("\t")[3::2]

    if cmdArgs.A:
        retA = detectPeaks(A)
        ansA = No + '\t' + time + '\t' + str(retA[0]) + '\t' + str(retA[1]) + '\t' + str(retA[2]) + '\n'
    else:
        ansA = "" #to get read of Unbound local var err
    if cmdArgs.B:
        retB = detectPeaks(B)
        ansB = No + '\t' + time + '\t' + str(retB[0]) + '\t' + str(retB[1]) + '\t' + str(retB[2]) + '\n'
    else:
        ansB = ""

    return ansA + ansB

def mkOutFilePath(outDirPath, inFilePath):
    inFilename = os.path.basename(inFilePath)
    return os.path.join(outDirPath, inFilename + ".peak")

def qFix(inFilePath):
    if inFilePath == '-':
        return sys.stdin
    else:
        return open(inFilePath, "r")

def processFile(inFilePath):
    '''
    if inFilePath == '-':
        inFile = sys.stdin
    else:
        inFIle = open(inFilePath, "r")
    '''
    inFile = qFix(inFilePath)

    if cmdArgs.outFiles == '-':
        outFile = sys.stdout
    elif os.path.isfile(cmdArgs.outFiles):
        outFile = open(cmdArgs.outFiles, "a")
    else:
        outFile = open(mkOutFilePath(cmdArgs.outFiles, inFilePath), "w")

    for line in inFile.readlines():
        if line[0] == '#':
            outFile.write(line)
        elif line[0] == 'N' and line[1] == 'r' :
            outFile.write("Nr\tTime\tX\tY\tValue\n")
        else:
            outFile.write(processFileLine(line))

def main():
    if cmdArgs.inFiles == '-':
        processFile('-')
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(cmdArgs.inFiles):
            filesList = [cmdArgs.inFiles]
        else:
            if cmdArgs.recuresive:
                filesList = [y for x in os.walk(cmdArgs.inFiles) for y in glob.glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.dat'))]
            else:
                filesList = glob.glob(os.path.join(cmdArgs.inFiles, '*.dat'))
        for filePath in filesList:
            processFile(filePath)

def checkPath(path):
    if (path != '-') and not os.path.exists(path):
        exit(2)
    return path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmdArgsParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument('inFiles', nargs='?', default='-', type=checkPath, help="Path to input file(s).")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument('outFiles', nargs='?', default='-', type=checkPath, help="Path to output file(s).")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument("-d", "--delete", action="store_true", help="Delete input files after procesing.")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument("-r", "--recuresive", action="store_true", help="Operate recuresively.")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument("-A", action="store_true", help="Use data from A set.")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument("-B", action="store_true", help="Use data from B set.")
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument("-V", "--version", action="version", version=__version__)
    cmdArgs = cmdArgsParser.parse_args()
    main()
```

Files read by the program have comments that are to be copied to the output.
Example file(simplified, there is lots of data in real ones):

> ```
> # Comments
> Nr:     Time    1A      1B      2A      2B      3A      3B      4A      4B
> 1       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 2       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10   0,10
> 3       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 4       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    -0,10   0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 5       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 6       2015    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,15    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 7       2015    0,10    0,20    0,30    0,20    0,10    0,10    0,10    0,10
> 8       2015    -0,10   0,10    0,10    0,10    -0,10   0,10    0,10    0,10
> ```

Output for sample file:

> ```
> # Commests
> Nr      Time    X       Y       Value
> 1       2015    0       0       0.2
> 2       2015    0       0       0.2
> 3       2015    0       0       0.2
> 4       2015    0       0       0.2
> 5       2015    0       0       0.2
> 6       2015    0       0       0.2
> 7       2015    0       0       0.2
> 8       2015    0       0       -0.2
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Follow the pep8 style guide.
2. In `detectPeaks`, you should slice `in_list` initially, rather than popping.  So `in_list[:-1]`.
3. In `detectPeaks`, you should convert to float in the initial list comprehension.
4. In `detectPeaks`, you should convert to a single numpy array, then slice that to get X and Y.
5. In `detectPeaks`, you don't need to wrap the `return` in `( )`
6. In `processFileLine`, don't put multiple operations on a single line like that.
7. In `processFileLine`, you should do the splitting once, then get the items from that.
8. In `processFileLine`, you should use string replacement.  So, for example, `ansA = '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(No, time, *retA)`.  Or better yet you can define a string `ansform = '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'` at the beginning, then apply the format to it in each case, so `ansA = 'ansform.format(No, time, *retA)` and `ansB = 'ansform.format(No, time, *retB)`.
9. Use `with` to automatically open and close files when you are done with them.
10. When looping over a file object, you don't need `readlines`.  Just do, for example, `for line in inFile`.  That will automatically loop over all the lines in the file.
11. In `processFile`, you should test for a slice of a string.  So `elif line[:2] == 'Nr':`
12. In the loop of `processFile`, it would be better to define a string in the `if...elif...else` block, and then after the block write that string.
13. Never, ever, under any circumstances call `exit`.  If you need to exit, either allow the program to exit normally or throw an exception.  In your case, raise an exception.
14. You should put the argument parsing in a function.
15. In `main`, you should `return` at the end of the `if cmdArgs.inFiles == '-':` block, which will allow you to avoid the `else` case.  Or better yet, do `if cmdArgs.inFiles == '-' or os.path.isfile(cmdArgs.inFiles):`, since `filesList = [cmdArgs.inFiles]` will work in both cases.
16. In `main`, you should do `elif cmdArgs.recuresive` (which is miss-spelled, by the way).
17. In `main`, the list comprehension should be a generator expression.  This will allow you to avoid having to store all the filenames.

Answer (score 3):

**Spelling counts**

The usability of your programme suffers if a flag is named `recuresive`, delete the second `e`.

**Repeat again**

You repeated a function in the docs of another function, why?

**Main should take args**

Main should take the command line flags as args and those should appear only in main, as it performs IO and other functions logic.

**Automatically closing files**

Use with to automatically close files. Not the manual open. open may leave the file open if an exception occurs.